# Error of EMA function under TTR

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to get the EMV function in the TTR package to work.

```
library("quantmod")
library("TTR")
getSymbols("EBT.AX")
EMV(LoHi(EBT.AX), Vo(EBT.AX), n=9, maType="EMA", vol.divisor=10000)
```

This produces the following error message:

```
Error in `[.xts`(HL, , 2) : subscript out of bounds.
```

According to the TTR documentation, EMV uses High-low (HL) prices. However *HL* doesn't work. I've used *LoHi* successfully for other indicators (e.g. DonchianChannel) but it doesn't work for EMV. The same error is produced using the following: `EMV(EBT.AX[,c("High","Low")],.....`.

I've also tried:

```
EMV(HLC(EBT.AX)[,-3], Vo(EBT.AX), n=9, maType="EMA", vol.divisor=10000)
```

but this produces the following error: `Error in runSum(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs.`  I've tried several different stocks and all produce the same errors but have no missing values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EMV` function will throw this error when either:

1. the High and Low are equal for any given period, or
2. the Volume is zero for any given period.

Correct both of those situations and the function will work.

```
EBT.AX[,2] <- EBT.AX[,2]+1e-6
EBT.AX[,5] <- EBT.AX[,5]+1e-6
emv <- EMV(HLC(EBT.AX)[,-3], Vo(EBT.AX), n=9, maType="EMA", vol.divisor=10000)
```